# JTattoo L&F not applying correctly on all Swing components, don't understand why...?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I installed and correctly applied the JTattoo L&F on my app, but for some reason the main JFrame, does not get the L&F! I think it has to do with the fact that it is instantiated in the main method using .setVisible(true); method, after the JTattoo L&F is instantiated for the whole app! I tried everything, including changing the L&F inside the JFrame's code itself, whatever I do, nothing works... it just won't budge! Looked for similar issues on Google, found nothing relevant, I've already spent a few good hours on this issue and can't figure it out, I tried everything! Including "reverse-engineering" some methods, nothing works!

Here's my code:

```
public class DsrApplication {
    public static MeniuPrincipalTaburi meniuTaburi = new MeniuPrincipalTaburi();
    public static boolean isAdmin;
    public static ArrayList<String> arrUti;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            //here you can put the selected theme class name in JTattoo
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.mint.MintLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DsrApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DsrApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DsrApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DsrApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        String connectionUrl = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", "127.0.0.1", "3306", "dsr");
        DataBaseConnection db = new DataBaseConnection(connectionUrl, "root", "@Root123#");
        Connection conn = db.getConnection();
        
        Logare logare = new Logare();
        meniuTaburi.setVisible(true);
        MeniuPrincipalTaburi.Meniu.addTabNoExit("Logare", logare.getContentPane());
        MeniuPrincipalTaburi.Meniu.setSelectedComponent(logare.getContentPane());

        Map<String, String> utilizatori = new HashMap<>();
        UtilizatoriDAO userManagement = new UtilizatoriDAO(conn);
        try {
            utilizatori = userManagement.getAll();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreeareUtilizatori.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Map<String, String> getUtilizatori = new HashMap<>();

        System.out.println(getUtilizatori.get("Admin"));

        FisierDAO fisierDB = new FisierDAO(db.getConnection());

        List<Fisier> fisiere = new ArrayList<>();

        fisiere = fisierDB.getAll();

        arrUti = userManagement.getNames();
    }
```

Here's the JFrame's code:

```
public class MeniuPrincipalTaburi extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form MeniuPrincipalTaburi
     */
    public static JTabbedPaneCloseButton Meniu = new JTabbedPaneCloseButton();
     
    public MeniuPrincipalTaburi() {
        Meniu.setEnabled(true);
        Meniu.setSize(1000, 500);
        this.setSize(1000, 500);
        this.add(Meniu);
        initComponents();
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Dragos\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\project\\Fisiere\\Alte Documente\\Logo\\transformator.png");
        this.setIconImage(img.getImage());
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Sistem informatic laborator");
        addContainerListener(new java.awt.event.ContainerAdapter() {
            public void componentAdded(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {
                formComponentAdded(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1008, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 665, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formComponentAdded(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.mint.MintLookAndFeel");
                /*if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }*/
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuPrincipalTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuPrincipalTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuPrincipalTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuPrincipalTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MeniuPrincipalTaburi().setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

As you can see, also tried to change the Nimbus L&F, in the JFrame's L&F code as well... still nothing!
If anybody would be kind enough to offer any hints, thanks guys.

Comment: 1) get rid of all your static variables. This indicates incorrect design on your classes 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 3) Why do you have main() methods in each of your classes.

Comment: #1) if I get rid of "static" then I can't use them inside the main method! #2) Fixed! #3) Because every time I create a new JFrame, they are there, I don't create them, Java does!

Comment: Nevermind guys, solved it my self! Created a swing.properties file and saved it where it's supposed to be and it's solved! Have a good evening! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CXvimHfSlo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: *#1) if I get rid of "static" then I can't use them inside the main method!* - If you want to use them inside the main() method. Then they should be defined in the main method. Like I suggested your classes are incorrectly designed. You should NOT be using static variables in that way. *I don't create them, Java does!* - Java doesn't create them, your IDE creates them. Don't use the IDE to generate your code. You are spending time learning the IDE and not learning Java/Swing. The IDE should only be used to organize the source files and to compile and debug. You should not have multiple frames.

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for many working examples of a better way to structure your code. Since I see your code is using a JTabbedPane, maybe start with the section on `How to Use Tabbed Panes`.